# How can i optimize my python code for speech recognition?

Tags: python, speech-recognition, speech-to-text, google-text-to-speech

I'm trying to implement a code that opens links from speech recognition. How can i write easily that if for example I said "google" it will go on specific branch and computer will ask me to dictate the link that it should follow to open google.com?
[**code**][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/B9Nrg.png
I have to rewrite the code under blue shape every time I want to say the link to be followed.

Comment: paste your code / sample data /desired output and error message to your question as text

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. It is important for the community that you *also* demonstrate that you are working to solve your issue. The best way to do that in my opinion is to include the **text** based version of the source code you have so far, even if it is not working quite right.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pyttsx3
import speech_recognition as sr
import webbrowser

speech_engine = sr.Recognizer()
speech_engine.energy_threshold = 300

def speak(text):
    engine = pyttsx3.init()
    engine.say(text)
    engine.runAndWait()   
#open web pages    
with sr.Microphone() as micro:
    print("Recording...")
    speak("Tell me what page do you need me to open")
    audio = speech_engine.record(micro, duration=5)
    print("Recognizing...")
    text = speech_engine.recognize_google(audio, language="en")
    print(text)
if text == 'ok':
    speak("what the fuck")
elif (text == 'open Amazon' or text =="Amazon"):
    webbrowser.open("https://amazon.com")
    print("opening Amazon")
elif (text == 'open Wikipedia' or text == "No"):
    with sr.Microphone() as micro:
        speak("Where do you need me to open it from?")
        audioo = speech_engine.record(micro, duration=15)
        print("Wait")
        text = speech_engine.recognize_google(audioo, language="en")
        print(text)
        webbrowser.open(text)
    print("opening Wikipedia")
elif (text == 'open Google' or text == 'Google'):
    with sr.Microphone() as micro:
        speak("Where do you need me to open it from?")
        audioo = speech_engine.record(micro, duration=15)
        print("Wait")
        text = speech_engine.recognize_google(audioo, language="en")
        print(text)
        webbrowser.open(text)
    #webbrowser.open("https://google.com")
    print("I've opened google for you")
elif (text == 'open Moodle' or text =="Moodle"):
    webbrowser.open("https://edu.tuiasi.ro")
    print("opening Moodle")
elif (text == 'open Gmail' or text =="Gmail" or text == "Google mail" or text =="Mail" or text =="mail"):
   with sr.Microphone() as micro:
    speak("Where do you need me to open it from?")
    audioo = speech_engine.record(micro, duration=15)
    print("Wait")
    text = speech_engine.recognize_google(audioo, language="en")
    print(text)
    webbrowser.open(text)
   # webbrowser.open("www.gmail.com")
    print("opening Gmail")
else:
    print("Unrecognized Command")
```

This code is working properly but i want something better in order not to use

```
with sr.Microphone() as micro:
        speak("Where do you need me to open it from?")
        audioo = speech_engine.record(micro, duration=15)
        print("Wait")
        text = speech_engine.recognize_google(audioo, language="en")
        print(text)
        webbrowser.open(text)
```

every time when i want to "communicate" with the computer.

Comment: you should edit your question and add the code to it instead of answering your own question